# SQL - Find Accounts with combination of Services

Tags: sql, nested, where-clause, zoho

apologies in advance, definitely new to SQL and I'm not sure I'm wording this the best.
I have a table that lists Accounts with their active Services. For example,

| Acct | Serviceid | ServiceName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 00001 | Tax Consulting |
| 1111 | 00004 | Home Insurance |
| 1112 | 00004 | Home Insurance |
| 1111 | 00003 | Auto Insurance |
| 1111 | 00002 | Bill Pay |
| 1112 | 00001 | Tax Consulting |

I'm trying to find Accts that have: 
Tax Consulting, Bill Pay, and Home Insurance 
OR 
Tax Consulting, Bill Pay, and Auto Insurance

 So they need to have '00001' and '00002' and/or '00003'/'00004'
Appreciate the help!

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Presumably, you would want accounts that have both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this.  A relatively concise method is:

```
select acct
from t
group by acct
having sum(case when serviceName = 'Tax Consulting' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when serviceName = 'Bill Pay' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when serviceName in ('Home Insurance', 'Auto Insurance') then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If you don't want accounts that have both insurances and services are not repeated, then you can use:

```
sum(case when serviceName in ('Home Insurance', 'Auto Insurance') then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```